# How to disable the zoom effect on my product images?

Tags: css, image, hover, weebly

I am using Weebly to create an online store, using a template and ran into something I dislike. Every time an user clicks on a product the product page comes up and if you hover over the product's image, a zoom function is initialized. How do I disable this effect?

I have a feeling that it is something simple like display:none; but I can't seem to figure out which class or whatever is associated with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simple way is to hide the element that is placed over the image on hover via CSS:

```
.cloud-zoom-big,
#cloud-zoom-big {
  display: none !important;
}
```

or

```
.mousetrap {
  display: none !important;
}
```

The better way would be to disable the JavaScript, that is calculating the effect. It's located in your `http://cdn2.editmysite.com/js/site/commerce-core.js` at the beginning of the file. But this file is minimized, so its hard to remove the relevant code.

Comment: I've already tried: #cloud-zoom-big {display: none !important;} and it didn't work. :(

Comment: Mh for me it worked... have you also tried the class `.cloud-zoom-big` ?

Comment: Yes I've tried both of them. I think you are right I will try to find the Java snippet calculating the effort like you said. Any suggestions what the code would look like

Comment: I have two .js files: custom.js and plugins.js

Comment: Found it and updated my questions, but will be hard to remove it... have you tried the `.mousetrap` class?

Comment: How can I access and edit that file? Is it even possible?

Comment: Also, I'm using Safari. Could this be the problem? Maybe the changes I do to css don't work on Safari?

Comment: I've tried all of the different ones already they all don't work :(

Comment: Safari should not be the problem. Are you sure you're editing the right CSS file? Do other (e.g. trivial) changes work? Do you have the possibility to edit the markup? Then another possibility would be to just remove the `<div class="mousetrap">`

Comment: I can insert the css code anywhere in the file main_style.css right?

Comment: Oh wait, I think I found the right file... I'll let you know in a second

Comment: Perfect, you helped a lot, I was looking in the wrong css file. Although all your answers should have worked but Weebly is a bit difficult at times.

Thanks a lot for your help!!!
<3

Comment: If you know a way to instead open the thumbnail pics in the product area instead of opening up the photos in tabs I would appreciate that as well.

Comment: The line of code that I have for that is:
<div id="wsite-com-product-images-strip" class="wsite-com-column-group">
   {{#images}}
    <a id="wsite-com-product-images-secondary-{{id}}"
     href="{{full_url}}" target="_blank"
     class="wsite-com-product-images-secondary wsite-com-column cloud-zoom-gallery"
     data-zoom-id="zoom1"
     data-small-image="{{thumbnail_url}}"
     >
     <div class="wsite-com-product-images-secondary-outer">
      {{{thumbnail_html}}}
      
     </div>

Comment: I would encourage you to ask the thumbnail problem as another question. Glad I could help.

Comment: OMG I love you for working my brain :) 

I added rel="lightbox" and now o'clock the thumbnails open up in lightbox. <3

Thanks for all your help again.

Answer (score 1):

It's not necessary to make any custom code changes.

The zoom is going to be based on the size of the image that you upload. So, say for example your image is 300 pixels by 300 pixels there will be no zoom. Zoom starts at about 640 pixels. So, just make sure your image is smaller than 640 pixels.

Note:
If your image is 3000 pixels by 3000 pixels the zoom is going to be great! And an image that is somewhere in the middle of that is going to have about half the amount of zoom.

Comment: *This should really be marked as the correct answer,.. because it **is** the correct answer ;)