# How to disable lightbox for my gallery and open each thumbnail photo in the main frame instead?

Tags: containers, gallery, thumbnails, lightbox, weebly

I would like to disable the lightbox effect for my product's gallery. And I would like to open each thumbnail photo in the main image container instead. (#wsite-com-product-images-main-image)

Is there an easy way to accomplish this? Here is the link to my page: http://poloniafoods.weebly.com/store/p9/Meat_Pierogies_%28400g%29.html

Thanks in advance,
Justin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's coded in the design of the Theme. *EDIT* `The default behavior would be that the thumbnail image that is clicked, would replace the default image.` So, go to:

1. Theme Tab
2. Edit HTML/CSS
3. Under Partials, go to:
4. Commerce
5. then product
6. images.tpl
7. Look for~> w-fancybox  (should be right after cloud-zoom-gallery)
8. Delete w-fancybox, save your changes and publish your site.

**There might be some other changes that you need to make. Your best bet would be to make a back up zip copy, if you are using a custom theme. Then replace the code in your images.tpl with one from a different theme. THEN there might some JavaScript change that you would need to alter as well. ~That's about all I got. Can't do it all for you, without charging you something for my time ;)

(see Screenshot)

[image]

Comment: Here is my next question, if this one is too long and complicated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39175185/how-to-create-a-read-more-layout-for-my-products-description-using-weebly

Comment: I don't see w-fancybox anywhere actually

Comment: It's working now, so I'm assuming you figured it out.

Comment: What you see now is the default, however i just want to remove the zooming when hover part and I can't seem to do it.

Comment: That would be My Answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38963759/3925032 (which I'm assuming you saw, because it's now marked as the correct answer). While it would require you to resize your images, that would be the correct way ;)

Comment: Yes, I think you're right. That's the easiest way and only way to do it in my case. Thanks again! <3