# How to create a read more layout for my product's description using Weebly?

Tags: text, show-hide, hidden, dropdown, weebly

My product's description is too long and the user needs to scroll far down the page to view the Add to Cart button. Is there any way of only showing a few lines of text, then have a "read more" link which would drop down the rest of the text?

I don't see anywhere in Weebly's product description where I have the option of adding code.

Here's my webpage: http://poloniafoods.weebly.com/store/p10/kozackie

Thanks in advance,
Justin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a question you should be asking Weebly, and asking them for a features request if there is no option..

If you are looking for code, you should really attempt to try to do some research, before asking. This took me a whole minute or so to find. Try this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38680734/3925032

~

Or, something like this: http://jedfoster.com/Readmore.js/